# Surface pro5 locks when I use touch screen or pen

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro

My new Microsoft surface pro5 has a problem when I use the touch screen. It locks the screen and I'll have to login in again.

This happens for instance when I touch a free area on the desktop and when I touch the windows button.

The same thing happens when I use the pen.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is just one option/solution I have found. We are using Surface's for Kiosks and Training Systems and we've had multiple Surface's with this same issue. This fix/workaround will only work on Win 10 Pro/Enterprise (due to Group Policy access).

If you restore the Windows Default Power Plan options (other than the Surface's mandatory Balanced Plan), you can use one of those other plans and that fixed our issue immediately and long term. For our purpose, we used the High Performance plan. This registry option will bring these default Power Plans back.

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power – Change CsEnabled to ‘1’**

Reboot. Then set your desired power options. Once you have configured your desired power settings, you then have to lock down the power options in Group Policy. Otherwise, every time you reboot, the Surface will force switch back to Balanced.

**Group Policy> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Select an active power plan** > set to High Performance (or what ever plan you want).

This will lock down the power settings so they can not be changed, unless you turn the Group Policy option back off (which you can do to adjust settings as needed).

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Boot surface in UEFI mode and exit from there (without changing anything). You will be all set.

Here is the link to boot the surface in UEFI mode.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023532/surface-how-do-i-use-the-bios-uefi

Raj